# How can we install fbprophet and pystan in conda prompt or in window prompt

Tags: cython, facebook-prophet, prophet, pystan

I have problem while installing fbprophet module in windows or in conda. In windows command prompt it says

> this error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip

while in conda prompt it says

> The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.

How I can install these modules?

I have tried using following commands:

```
pip install pystan 
pip install fbprophet
```

OR

```
conda install pystan -c conda-forge
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Comment: Note that it's `pip install prophet` (not **fb**prophet) - https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python